# CDI session bean initialization

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I have two beans:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Session implements Serializable {
    private String temp;
    +getter, setter

}

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Test {
    @Inject
    private Session s;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.sth = s.getTemp(); //here is exception
    }
}
```

When I try to fetch in init same value from session I get NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong? Server is JBoss eap 6.0, JSF v2.1. Thanks in advance

Edit: I investigated that problem appears only when I have more than 11 items in primefaces submenu component. If I have less than 11 items every thinks work OK. I am using PrimeFaces v 3.5.
Edit 2: On session bean only constructor is invoked. I have method annotated with PostConstruct but it is not called. I always get NullPointerException after invoking any method on session from Test bean.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using `RequestScoped` and `SessionScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package? If you are, replace them with those from `javax.enterprise.context` package.

Comment: I just checked and in both cases I use javax.enterprise.context

Comment: I must ask one more thing. As `Session` is very often used name for class and it exists in many packages, are you sure that `Session` class is that you created, not imported from, for example `javax.mail` or something else?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that imports are correct

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you call `s.getTemp()` outside of the `@PostConstruct` method?

Comment: Yes it is working. Even if I come to this page that bean test is used  from link it is working. It seems it is not working when I type directly address in web browser.

Comment: I think it is primefaces issue because I get null exception only when in submenu items length is greater than 11.  If number of items in submenu is less than 11 it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you post the relevant JSF / Primefaces code?