# Difference between RequestScoped/SessionScoped in javax.faces.bean and javax.enterprise.context

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411009/java-ee-session-bean-initialization) @partlov added comment that we can use `RequestScoped`/`SessionScoped` from two packages - `javax.faces.bean` and `javax.enterprise.context`. I'm new in JSF/Java EE and I don't know the dfference. I use a lot of `RequestScoped`/`SessionScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package. I will be grateful if somebody will write the difference.

Comment: Read [JSF: Backing beans (@ManagedBean) or CDI Beans (@Named)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/jsf-backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named) and [Comparing JSF Beans, CDI Beans and EJBs](http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/comparing-jsf-beans-cdi-beans-and-ejbs/) to start with.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read that.